# Cannot get rid of persisting highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlight, highlighting

I switched from macos to linux and have spontaneous highlighting in my document. I tried to get rid of it by doing the following command without success:

```
hi clear
no syntax
nohlsearch
noh
```

The randomly highlighted pattern is for example in the following line written in python, the strings `numpy` and `savetxt` are highlighted:

```
#from numpy import savetxt
```

when I uncomment the the line, the highlighting disapears

```
from numpy import savetxt
```

Here is a screenshot of the highlighting:

[image]

The highlighting disappeared after inserting in the `.vimrc`:

```
set nospell
```

But but I thin it then anihi

---

late the command:

```
set spellang=en
set spell
```

int the `.vimrc`

What should I do?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "persisting" or "spontaneous" highlighting. Do you want to turn off syntax highlighting? Everywhere? Try `:syntax off`. Note that highlighting of search terms is a different animal.

Comment: @BLayer: many thanks for your comment. I also tried `:syntax off`: this removed the (helpful) syntax highlighting but didn't remove the "random" other bothersome highlighting

Comment: You're welcome. Can you describe in detail what those other highlighting things are and do so in your question? (Hit that "Edit" link.) Before you do see `:h 'nohls'`, though.

Comment: Could be spelling inside comments

Comment: thanks again for the comments @BLayer and @D.BenKnoble. I added the better example of the problem. I read the paragraph `:h 'nohls'` but could still not solve the problem unortunately

Comment: screenshot would provide a lot of help. Anyway, run `:set nospell`.

Comment: Many thans for your comment @MaximKim. It helped a lot but might render `set spelllang=en` and `set spell` useless, right?

Comment: @ecjb activate `spell` when you need it. To toggle use `:set spell!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you have `set spell` enabled which usually checks spelling in comments.

If you don't need it turn it off with `:set nospell`. Activate when you need it with `:set spell`.

To toggle use `:set spell!`.

Map it if you do it often, for example:

```
nnoremap yos :set spell!<CR>
```

Then `yos` will toggle spelling.

Comment: many thanks for your answer @MaximKim